# How to hide div if conditions from GET request data are met

Tags: javascript, jquery, function, get

I have a div that's being populated by GET request data. I want to make it so that if certain conditions are not met (there isn't any data) then the div is hidden. It was working when I was using a local JSON file, but since I switched to REST and axios I've had to convert what I have.

When I run `console.log(admText.length)` I'm getting a `0` and the div is hidden in the browser, but the user's data that I've rendered *does* contain data. Therefore, their page should show that div.

I have a feeling that my `if` statement is in the wrong place, but I'm not sure where it could go. Putting it in the `let admText` block results in an error.

#### JS snippet:

```
import $ from 'jquery';
import DataTable from 'datatables.net';

export default class {
    constructor() {

    }

    loadAdmData(response) {
        let admText = response.map(function(val) {
            return {
                "Status": val.AdmStatus,
                "Classification": val.Classification
            }
        })

        if (admText.length == "") $("#adm-tab").hide();
         // if (!admText.length)  $("#adm-tab").hide(); // was working w/ local JSON file

        console.log(admText.length);   // shows `0`, which isn't correct

    $('#adm-table').DataTable({
        columns: [
          { data: "Status" },
          { data: "Classification" }
       ... etc
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure `response` is an array? if you're getting it from a GET it could be a JSON string. 
.map() is going to return an array so `admText` is an array and since you're getting `.length` as  `'0'` that means your mapping function is failing for some reason.
you should try `console.log(response);` and `console.log(admText);` to see what you're putting inside of the map and what you're getting out of it.

Comment: I'm getting: `[object Object],[object.....]` and `[object Object],[object.....` for both.

Comment: At least you know `response` isn't a string. try adding `console.log(val);` inside the `.map()` before the `return`

Comment: By doing that I'm getting: `[object Object]{AdmStatus: "Active", Classification:.....`, which is the data I was looking for.